# How to extract the running process using prometheus node exporter?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

> I have downloaded the prometheus node exporter in prometheus official site https://prometheus.io/download/ for my linux system.

If i run the node exporter file , it is running fine and able to see the metrics in 9100 port.

In 9100 metrics , i am looking to extract the running process (for example: i need to extract any running application like 'chrome' browser) , but i do not have any config files inside the node exporter directory to filter the running process.

Is their any commands available to filter the required running process in node exporter like,
./node_exporter "filter process like 'chrome'"

can i use "prometheus.yml" file 'labels' to filter running process in my linux system.

Kindly suggest me , how to extract the running process and system details in node exporter.

Comment: Do you mean you have the process statistics but want to filter them or do you mean you have no process metrics and wonder if there is a filter preventing that ? There is no config file, all options are on the command line (easier to operate in a container).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Node Exporter is oriented towards providing measurements on machine-level (kernel|OS) metrics.

It is possible to configure Node exporter to surface aggregate (!) process measurements but not possible to configure it to surface per-process measurements. The reasoning is that measurements over a reasonable number of processes could swamp the exporter.

There is a (companion) solution that will permit you to report on a filtered set of processes. I've not used this but found it while responding to your question:

https://github.com/ncabatoff/process-exporter

Comment: I've seen `process-exporter` used and it's pretty impressive. IIRC there was even a really cool Grafana dashboard for it (there are a handful if you search, not sure which one I saw).